# Open link in new window when command key is pressed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos

I'm using Javascript to open links and I want to open the links in a new tab when the "command" key is pressed on an Apple computer. Right now, I have this:

```
$(document).on('click','a[data-id]',function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey||expressionForCommandKey){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user does command+click on a link, the default behaviour is to open it in a new tab or window depending on user settings. Just give the user a link, no script required. Otherwise, dispatch a [mouse event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent) (also see [MDN Mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)) with appropriate values on the "link".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just user normal anchor behavior and target a new window (tab in new browsers)?

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a>`

But if there's some higher reason for you using this, try:

```
$(document).on('click','a[data-id]',function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){
        // command was used
    }
});
```